# Change max number of authors displayed in references in Customized CurVe CV

Tags: biblatex, overleaf

I have a specific question about this template.

A Customised CurVe CV https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/a-customised-curve-cv/mvmbhkwsnmwv

How to display all the names in a publication? (currently it uses an ellipsis for middle authors, if there are many)

I have tried to use eg maxnames=99 in the require[maxnames=99]{biblatex}, and also in the call to printbibliography, but neither work.

Comment: If you've retained the style=apa6 option (in settings.sty), you will still see the author list shortened with ellipsis. If you replace this with style=authoryear along with maxnames=99, you will get the whole list. When posting questions here, it would be better to provide a minimal example. In this case, the question is really about biblatex options, not the CurVe CV template.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't make it work with apa6 and I changed the style to apa in settings.sty. The apa style has the option `apamaxprtauth=<num>` that sets the number of authors displayed.

http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex-contrib/biblatex-apa/biblatex-apa.pdf